# Custom post types templates

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, template-hierarchy

I have registered a custom post type called "Services" but when I am giving the single post the template "single-services.php" its not accepting this but choosing the "homepage.php" template can u tell the problem? It is also not taking the "archive-services.php" template but instead using the blog template (index.php)

UPDATE. Here's the code:

```
add_action('init', 'services_register');
function services_register() {

$labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Services', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Service', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'service'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Service'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Service'),
    'new_item' => __('New Service'),
    'view_item' => __('View Service'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Service'),
    'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_icon' => null,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail')
  ); 

register_post_type( 'services' , $args );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply registering a custom post type called 'services" then your register code should look like
register_post_type( 'services', $args );
Make sure the word "services" is exact in register_post_type. And
Your post_type word should be max. 20 characters, can not contain capital letters or spaces

Also make sure your has_archive parameter is set true like this
'has_archive' => true,

And don't forget to flush the rewrite rule by clicking save in permalink setting in your backend after any change in the slug or permalink.Hope this helps you